# Getting a string input from user in C++

Tags: c++

This is the piece of code I am getting error in. Yes I have `using namespace std

```
string age2;

cin.ignore();

getline(cin, age2);

cout << "Your age is " << age2;
```

This is giving me error -> "getline is not defined"

I tried searching up and tried all the solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: how are you building this?

Comment: did you `#include <string>` ? It helps if you show all your code.

Comment: But why, why are you `using namespace std`?  You should try: `using std::string, std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

std::string age;

std::cin.ignore();

std::getline(std::cin, age);

std::cout << "Your age is " << age;

return 0;
}
```

so there must be something your missing in your example

also if your doing age, you should use an int instead of a string, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

int age;

std::cin.ignore();

std::cin >> age;

std::cout << "Your age is " << age;

return 0;
}
```